# Unable to work with FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to use Symfony2 and FOSRestBundle to come up with a REST framework and I am failing miserably.

I have done the following:

in my deps file:

```
[FOSRest]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRest.git
    target=fos/FOS/Rest

[FOSRestBundle]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle.git
    target=bundles/FOS/RestBundle

[JMSSerializerBundle]
    git=git://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle.git
    target=bundles/JMS/SerializerBundle
```

In my apps/config.yml

```
fos_rest:
    view:
        formats:
            rss: true
            xml: false
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig


sensio_framework_extra:
    view:
        annotations: false
```

In my Controller:

```
namespace Rest\WebServiceBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;  


class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction($name)
    {


  $view = View::create()
          ->setStatusCode(200)
          ->setData($name);
        return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);


    }
}
```

When I go to the URL: http://local.symfony.com/web/app_dev.php/hello/test

I get:

```
Unable to find template "".
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
2 linked Exceptions: Twig_Error_Loader » Twig_Error_Loader
```

The documentation seems confusing to me and I am unable to continue. All I want is to be able to pass an array of data to the controller and get back a JSON format. Can someone help?

Comment: I'm also having trouble getting this going. It seems quite confusing for what seems like a relatively simple task. Have you had any luck with it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In `formats` section of `config.yml` you have to enable json format and disable other formats and set default `_format` value as json in route. e.g

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    view:
        formats:
            json: true
            rss: false # removing them will also work
            xml: false
#.......

#bundle/routing.yml
route_name:
  pattern: /route
  defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Controller:Method, _format:json }
```

Or, in controller you can do

```
$view->setFormat('json');
```

Also checkout the example links given in the documentation.

Comment: It worked for me too, but only when i use an array as data, what if i want to output an object?

Comment: Doesn't work with the newer versions. A more recent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18035437/842697. The comments are very interesants.