# FOS rest bundle: unable to find template

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I get the exception:

> Unable to find template ""

The other similar questions didn't help; and weirdly enough it was working fine and then suddenly started giving me this exception.

composer:

> ```
>    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.13.*@dev",
>    "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.12.*@dev",
> ```

I'm following [Automatic route generation: single RESTful controller (for simple resources)](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md)

config:

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener: true
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
    serializer:
        serialize_null: true

sensio_framework_extra:
    view:    { annotations: false }
    router:  { annotations: true }
```

routing:

```
sectors:
    type: rest
    prefix: /{v}
    resource: JJ\MainBundle\Controller\SectorsController
```

controller:

```
/**
 * @RouteResource("Sector")
 */
class SectorsController extends Controller
...
    public function cgetAction()
    {
        return $this->getSectorIndustryRepo()->findAll();
    }
```

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32779936/828366

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by setting the listener explicitly to false:

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener: false
```

**EDIT**

This also works:

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        prefer_extension: false
        default_priorities:
            - json
```

Comment: I don't think it is the right solution. You just turned off the whole Content Negotiation feature.

Comment: That is not what I told you here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/518#issuecomment-22162359. But yeah, it is a matter of configuration.

Thing is, either you use extension as preferred way to set the `format` which is bad but... anyway, just turn the `prefer_extension` parameter to `true`, or you use the `Accept` header and you have to configure priorities (Content Negotiation feature).

Answer (score 6):

For FOSRestBundle version 2.0 the config should be

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            prefer_extension: false
            fallback_format: json
```

Answer (score 4):

(For reference) If One is testing with a rest client or manually be sure to set the header in your request:
Accept:application/json

Because fosRestBundle tries to determine the proper response type from the headers in the request.

Comment: This helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Annotate your controller action with `@View` to resolve this issue.

```
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
```

Have a look at the documentation [chapter View Response listener](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md#view-response-listener).

---

If you don't want to annotate every action - you can set the @View annotation for a complete class using [my pull request here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/pull/471).

Add this to your composer.json to use the PR.

```
"require": {
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "dev-dev-view-addition as 0.12.0", 

// ...

"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/nifr/FOSRestBundle"
    },
```

Comment: Unable to find template "MainBundle:Sectors:cget.html.twig". I'm already using the extra bundle; config updated