# Unable to find template when returning response with FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using FOS Rest Bundle to build an Api, the problem is that every time I try to return anything I get the error message: "Unable to find template" I don't really want to render a template, but to serialize an entity that I have.

Here is my code:

**routing.yml:**

```
acme_api_register:
    pattern: /user
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeApiBundle:User:post, _format: json }
    requirements:
          _method: POST
```

**controller.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\ApiBundle\Controller;

use Acme\ApiBundle\Entity\Patient;
use Acme\ApiBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;

//use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

    class UserController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @View()
         */
        public function postAction()
        {
            $user = new Patient();

            $user->setName("Daniel");
            $user->setLastName("My lastName");
            $user->setEmail("pleasework@gmail.com");

            return $user;
        }
    }
```

and my **app/config.yml**

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    view: { annotations: false}
    router: { annotations: true }

fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - prefer_extension: false
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
```

I would appreciate any help a lot!

PD:

**composer.json:**

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.13.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "symlink",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [FOS rest bundle: unable to find template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010784/fos-rest-bundle-unable-to-find-template)

Answer (score 4):

This happens because you're probably using a browser to test your API. If you open your console inspector you'll see what's the request your browser is sending to your API. As you can see the **Accept** header looks something like:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

As you can see the first accepted format is **text/html**. That's why I guess your application is trying to return an HTML response, but it can't find the template!

So I suggest you disable the **html** format if you don't need it and set **json** as the default format.

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            fallback_format: json
            prefer_extension: false
            priorities: [json, xml]
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
        formats:
            json: true
            xml: true
            jsonp: false
            rss: false
            html: false
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
```

With such configuration you're saying that the only formats you support are **json** and **xml** and, if none is specified, use **json**.
Now open your browser again and you'll get your resource as an XML. That's because the **Accept** header is still `Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`. Your browser doesn't know you're calling a Rest API and what's your preferred format :-)

To test your API I suggest you use a proper client. If you're using Chrome then take a look at the [Advanced REST client](http://chromerestclient.appspot.com/) extension.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the wrong controller, try using the **FOSRestController** instead. Your controller code should be something like this.

```
<?php

    namespace Acme\ApiBundle\Controller;

    use Acme\ApiBundle\Entity\Patient;
    use Acme\ApiBundle\Entity\User;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;
    use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;


    class UserController extends FOSRestController
    {
        /**
         * @View()
         */
        public function postUserAction()
        {
            $user = new Patient();

            $user->setName("Daniel");
            $user->setLastName("My lastName");
            $user->setEmail("pleasework@gmail.com");

            return $user;
        }
    }
```

For more info take a look over [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html)

Also your routing should be defined like this.

**routing.yml**

```
users:
    type:     rest
    resource: Acme\ApiBundle\Controller\UsersController
```

FOSRest can automatically generate the routes for you if you stick to the rules as explained in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html).

Please take your time and read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html) since it looks obvious that you didn't if I look at your code.

Comment: Hi, I tried changing the parent controller class to FOSRestController, however, the error, persists, then I realized that your answer has a different action than the one I wrote, "postUserAction" instead of "postAction".

If I change this, I get "The controller for URI \"\/user\" is not callable" error

Comment: I changed my answer... And again please make sure you read the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)

Comment: Actually I did read the docs, but none of those worked for me, the auto generated routes are not found anyway... I'm done with this, is just a waste of time, I ended up using plain symphony.

Besides, If I stick to the docs, there is no mention of FOSRestController, but of FosRestController and son on... Thanks for your tone ;) Not voting down however ;)

Comment: FYI: The link to the routing documentation is broken. Update to [http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html)

Answer (score 1):

I know you said in a comment you were giving up but you should try this if you still want to build a REST api.
I think your `config.yml` is wrong. You have to specify what is the priority of the page formats to be sure that the first selected is `json` (even if you wrote it in the route, it's not enough).

Try to change your config file to be like this :

```
#...
fos_rest:
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
    format_listener:
        default_priorities: ['json', 'html', '*/*']
        fallback_format: json
        prefer_extension: true
#...
```

Here is a really good article on how to build correct REST Api :

http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/